# How to get ALL subdirectories, all levels deep except files in AWS S3 with python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

There are a lot of similar questions but I don't find an answer to exactly on this question. How to get ALL sub-directories starting from an initial one. The depth of the sub-directories is unknown.

Lets say I have:

```
data/subdir1/subdir2/file.csv
data/subdir1/subdir3/subdir4/subdir5/file2.csv
data/subdir6/subdir7/subdir8/file3.csv
```

So I would like to either get a list of all sub-directories all length deep OR even better all the paths one level before the files. In my example I would ideally want to get:

```
data/subdir1/subdir2/
data/subdir1/subdir3/subdir4/subdir5/
data/subdir6/subdir7/subdir8/
```

but I could work with this as well:

```
data/subdir1/
data/subdir1/subdir2/
data/subdir1/subdir3/
data/subdir1/subdir3/subdir4/
etc...
data/subdir6/subdir7/subdir8/
```

My code so far only gets me one level deep of directories:

```
result = await self.s3_client.list_objects(
    Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter="/"
)

subfolders = set()
for content in result.get("CommonPrefixes"):
    print(f"sub folder : {content.get('Prefix')}")
    subfolders.add(content.get("Prefix"))

return subfolders
```

Comment: Note that there is no real folder structure in S3 and thus no need to navigate it. "In S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, and objects are stored in buckets. S3 _has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system._ However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. It does this by _using a shared name prefix for objects_ (that is, objects have names that begin with a common string)." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import os

# list_objects returns a dictionary. The 'Contents' key contains a
# list of full paths including the file name stored in the bucket
# for example: data/subdir1/subdir3/subdir4/subdir5/file2.csv
objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='bucket_name')['Contents']

# here we iterate over the fullpaths and using 
# os.path.dirname we get the fullpath excluding the filename
for obj in objects:
    print(os.path.dirname(obj['Key'])
```

---

To make this a unique sorted list of directory "paths", we would use sort a set comprehension inline.  Sets are unique, and sorted will convert this to a list.

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

```py
import os
paths = sorted({os.path.dirname(obj['Key']) for obj in objects})
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain the code