# How to get ONLY bottom level sub-folders from amazon S3 with aioboto3 fast and asynchronously

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, concurrency, boto3

I have asked similar questions [How to get ALL subdirectories, all levels deep except files in AWS S3 with python boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69566632/how-to-get-all-subdirectories-all-levels-deep-except-files-in-aws-s3-with-pytho)and there are also others who have SIMILAR problems but this is more specific. I can get all sub-folders of any arbitrary depth from S3 using boto3 client (or aioboto3 for asycnhronous code) BUT it is very slow and it brings me back ALL the objects which I then filter using code like this:

```
    subfolders = set()
    prefix_tasks = [get_subfolders(bucket, prefix) for prefix in prefixes]
    try:

        for prefix_future in asyncio.as_completed(prefix_tasks):
            prefix_subfolders = await prefix_future
            subfolders.update(prefix_subfolders)

    except KeyError as exc:
        print(f"Scanning origin bucket failed due to: {exc}")
        raise exc
```

where my `get_subfolders` function is:

```
async def get_subfolders(self, bucket: str, prefix: str) -> Set[str]:

    subfolders = set()

    result = await self.s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix)
    objects = result.get("Contents")
    subfolders.update(await self._get_paths_by_depth(objects=objects, depth=4))

    # Use next continuation token for pagination for truncated results.
    while result["IsTruncated"]:
        result = await self.s3_client.list_objects_v2(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Prefix=prefix,
            ContinuationToken=result["NextContinuationToken"],
        )
        objects = result.get("Contents")
        subfolders.update(await self._get_paths_by_depth(objects=objects, depth=4))

    return subfolders
```

and my `get_paths_by_depth()` function is :

```
    async def get_paths_by_depth(self, objects: dict, depth: int) -> Set[str]:
    subfolders = set()
    current_path = None
    try:
        # Get only paths with depth equal to 'depth' levels
        for bucket_object in objects:
            current_path = os.path.dirname(bucket_object["Key"])
            if current_path.count("/") == depth:
                subfolders.add(current_path)

    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Getting subfolders failed due to error: {exc}")
        raise exc

    return subfolders
```

Any way to speed things up? I deally I would like to avoid bringing back all files and then filtering out the paths. Can I ask for paths of specific length right away?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your directory structure and what you are wanting as the result set (similar to how you did it in your other question)?

Comment: yeah I actually found a way I ll post it below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the file structure I have is something like:

```
prefix/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/file1.txt
prefix/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/file2.json
prefix/subfolder4/subfolder5/file3.json
prefix/subfolder6/subfolder7/subfolder8/
```

and I only want to get the paths that end with at least one file in the above case I want to have at the end:

```
prefix/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/
prefix/subfolder4/subfolder5/
```

So far with the code I posted in the question I was looking at each single file in the bucket and keeping its path in a set. That worked but took way too long.

A much much faster way is to use the `Delimiter` parameter in the S3 request. Specifically I used the "." delimiter which changes the response of the s3_client and it includes all CommonPrefixes in the bucket which include a ".". Since all files include a "." I get all the common prefixes with a single request instead of checking each file. The new code is this :

```
async def get_subfolders(
    self, bucket: str, prefix: str, delimiter: str = "."
) -> Set[str]:

    subfolders = set()
    foldername = None
    try:
        paginator = self.s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects")
        async for result in paginator.paginate(
            Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter=delimiter
        ):
            for obj in result.get("CommonPrefixes", []):
                foldername = os.path.dirname(obj["Prefix"])
                # Get only paths with depth greater or equal than S3_FOLDERS_PATH_DEPTH
                if foldername.count("/") >= S3_FOLDERS_PATH_DEPTH:
                    subfolders.add(foldername)

    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Getting subfolders failed due to error: {exc}")
        raise exc

    return subfolders
```